# How to place a windows form in screen coords and close it on command?

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous

I am working on a c# console program on Windows to move a window, as part of this I am trying to create a transparent box at the target destination to give the user a visual confirmation of the new location. I am currently facing 2 main problems:

1. I want to place the form in screen coordinates
2. I want to be able to close the window after the user has confirmed their decision.

Currently I have code in a library that my console client is calling that does this:

```
    public static void CreateBox(Rect rectangle)
    {
        Form f = new Form();
        f.Name = BoxName;
        f.BackColor = Color.Blue;
        f.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        f.Bounds = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(rectangle.Left, rectangle.Top, rectangle.Right - rectangle.Left, rectangle.Bottom - rectangle.Top);
        f.TopMost = true;
        f.Opacity = 0.5;

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Task.Run(() => Application.Run(f));
    }
```

And after searching some questions on here I have come up with this to attempt to close the form later:

```
    public static void RemoveBox()
    {
        Form f = Application.OpenForms[BoxName];

        if (f != null)
        {
            f.Close();
        }
    }
```

This is throwing an exception as its coming from a different thread, how can I close this window, and how can I place it in screen coordinates exactly where it should go?

EDIT:

I am now using this to attempt to find the box to move/close it unsuccessfully:

```
    public static void CreateBox(Rect rectangle)
    {
        Form f = new Form();
        f.Name = BoxName;
        f.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
        f.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        f.TopMost = true;
        f.Opacity = 0.3;

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Application.Run(f);
        });

        MoveBox(rectangle);
    }

    public static void RemoveBox()
    {
        IntPtr hWnd = FindBox(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1));
        var proc = Process.GetProcesses().Where(p => p.Handle == hWnd).Single();
        if (proc == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        proc.Kill();
    }

    public static void MoveBox(Rect rect)
    {
        IntPtr hWnd = FindBox(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1));
        MoveWindow(hWnd, rect);
    }

    private static IntPtr FindBox(TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
        IntPtr hWnd = IntPtr.Zero;

        while(DateTime.Now < time.Add(timeout) || hWnd != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            hWnd = FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, BoxName);
        }

        return hWnd;
    }
```

Issues with this:

1. I can't let the FindBox call take long at all because my goal is to make this box appear and snap windows to them as the user drags them and needs to move as they move it around the desktop.
2. the p.Handle == hWnd check in the RemoveBox function throws and access denied exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you want do just get it working put:
    Form.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;

Into your constructor, I do not recommend it however, since it will make the whole Form no longer be thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT : Here is a quick test I've done using a WinForm. It should run fine on console as well.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //Globals
    Form f;
    Task t;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        f = new Form();
        f.Name = "testForm";
        f.BackColor = Color.Blue;
        f.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        f.Bounds = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
        f.TopMost = true;
        f.Opacity = 0.5;

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();

        //f.Show();
         t = Task.Run(() => Application.Run(f));
    }


    private void btn_CloseForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (f.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new CloseForm_Delegate(CloseForm));
        }
    }

    delegate void CloseForm_Delegate();
    private void CloseForm()
    {
        f.Close();
    }



    private void btn_MoveForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (f.InvokeRequired)
        {
            //set form position here
            this.Invoke(new MoveForm_Delegate(MoveForm), new Point(0, 0));

        }
    }

    delegate void MoveForm_Delegate(Point p);
    private void MoveForm(Point p)
    {
        f.Location = p;
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course, I don't know why I didn't think to use MoveWindow, already using that throughout the program, will try that and the process kill function. Thanks!

Comment: Process.GetProcessesByName is not finding my process but I assume I am incorrectly assuming the name of my process, I am using the name of my form as the name I am searching for, how do I find out what the name of my process is or how do I set it?

Comment: I'm sorry, my solution would work only with an external process. IE, you could compile a simple winform program containing the transparent screen and Start it with Process.Start(). Then my solution would work. If you don't want that I suggest you put your Form as global and create two invoke procedure to move and close it.

Comment: What do you mean by put the form as global and create invoke procedures?